# Running apps that require unrooted system?

Tags: android-x86

I am trying to run Standard Chartered's app in android-x86, but I get the error:

```
This application is not supported on rooted 
devices. Please restore or update your device.
(code: 4)
```

Since I am running 8.1rc1 updating is not really possible, and since this is a brand new installation, restoring the device does not really make sense.

How can I either unroot the device or at least make the app think the device is unrooted?

Comment: Do root-hiding apps like Chainfire's [SUhide](https://suhide.com/) make the app think your device is unrooted?

Comment: From the description SUhide only works on ARM and ARM64.

Comment: Magisk Manager comes with hiding root feature. Otherwise, you can try RootCloack xposed module. Both are available for x86.